# Windows device portal returns 500

Tags: windows, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to connect to wifi using Windows Device Portal by REST API.

Request I'm sending:

```
http://localhost:50080/api/wifi/network?interface=<guid>&op=connect&ssid=<encoded wifi name>&key=<encoded password>&createprofile=no
```

But it returns 500 response.
Device discovery is enabled.

When I'm using web interface I can't connect either. It returns 500 error to console too.

Is there any way to connect to wifi using Windows Device Portal and rest api?

Comment: If you have any ideas how to list and connect to wifis on windows by script, you are welcome to recommend them to me.